# How to dump MySQL data starting from a specific date

Tags: mysql

can someone help me to dump mysql with spesific date so i can import to my other sites , i'm using seperate mysql database.

recently i've tried

```
 MYDATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
 mysqldump -u USER -p PASSWORD -h DBSERVER --where="date_pulled='$MYDATE'" DATABASE --tables TABLES1 TABLES2 TABLES3 > dumper.sql
```

i got error unknown WHERE

i've tried lots of code including what i've found in here,

thank you before for the one who read and for who replied :D

**UPDATE**

i use this

```
 --where="post_date >= '2015-06-01 00:00:00'"
```

and it worked , just change the post_date with whatever your column name

Comment: Have you found official documentation stating this can actually be done? You should look at the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 0):

your command look good. i have tested on my server and it works. Which error give your command ?

```
$ MYDATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
$ mysqldump -uroot -pxxxxx --where="id='$MYDATE'" bb --tables cmp1 cmp2
```

Comment: this is where the error part : mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `dvd_arsocial_lite_fan` WHERE date_pulled='2016-05-29'': Unknown column 'date_pulled' in 'where clause' (1054)

Comment: @uicebyah - post the result from : **SHOW CREATE TABLE dvd_arsocial_lite_fan;** to see if there a column date_pulled

Comment: | dvd_arsocial_lite_fan | CREATE TABLE `dvd_arsocial_lite_fan` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `display_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `update_time` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `counter_data` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: yes, there is no column **date_pulled** only created_date or updated_date and so you must use one of them in your where